# Dominio propio sin IP fija

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi, dominio, ip

- He comprado el dominio **suspekain.eus** en dinahosting
- Tengo **ekain.duckdns.org** apuntando a mi servidor web (raspberry pi)
- **suspekain.eus** redirecciona a **ekain.duckdns.org**

El problema esta en que quiero que en mi pagina aparezca mi dominio y no el de duckdns.

Comment: Una redireccion hace precisamente eso, cambiar el dominio al que apuntas, por lo que no vas a conseguir que aparezca tu dominio. En su lugar, yo optaria por hacer una entrada en el dns (por ej, web.suspekain.eus) que sea del tipo CNAME, y que apunte al dominio ekain.duckdns.org

Answer (score 0):

Aunque falta algo de información en tu pregunta, como por ejemplo como tienes configurado el servicio en el gestor de tu dominio y la configuración del servicio de ekain (menos relevante para este caso), creo que tu problema está en que en el gestor de tu dominio has configurado la opción "re-direccionamiento" y lo envías a ekain y allí le dices que hacer con tu dominio.

Si mi suposición es correcta, esa es la razón que salga el dominio del destino direccionado. Para que tu dominio suspekain.eus funcione correctamente en internet debes configurar el servicio DNS de tu gestor de dominio y definir el/los puntos de acceso (ns) que proporcionen ekain.dickdns.org (si existen).

Esto permitirá que se haga de forma transparente la resolución de la IP para tu dominio que es la IP de tu raspberry que conoce ekain y que sea tu dominio el que se vea en el navegador.